# Goroutines not exiting when data channel is closed

Tags: parallel-processing, go, goroutine

I'm trying to follow along the bounded goroutine example that is posted at http://blog.golang.org/pipelines/bounded.go.  The problem that I'm having is that if there are more workers spun up then the amount of work to do, the extra workers never get cancelled.  Everything else seems to work, the values get computed and logged, but when I close the `groups` channel, the workers just hang at the range statement.

I guess what I don't understand (in both my code and the example code) is how do the workers know when there is no more work to do and that they should exit?

**Update**

A working (i.e. non-working) example is posted at http://play.golang.org/p/T7zBCYLECp. It shows the deadlock on the workers since they are all asleep and there is no work to do. What I'm confused about is that I think the example code would have the same problem.

Here is the code that I'm currently using:

```
// Creates a pool of workers to do a bunch of computations
func computeAll() error {
    done := make(chan struct{})
    defer close(done)

    groups, errc := findGroups(done)

    // start a fixed number of goroutines to schedule with
    const numComputers = 20     
    c := make(chan result)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(numComputers)
    for i := 0; i < numComputers; i++ {
        go func() {
            compute(done, groups, c)
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(c)
    }()

    // log the results of the computation
    for r := range c { // log the results }

    if err := <-errc; err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

Here is the code that fills up the channel with data:

```
// Retrieves the groups of data the must be computed
func findGroups(done <-chan struct{}) (<-chan model, <-chan error) {
    groups := make(chan model)
    errc := make(chan error, 1)
    go func() {
        // close the groups channel after find returns
        defer close(groups)

        group, err := //... code to get the group ...
        if err == nil {
            // add the group to the channel
            select {
                case groups <- group:
            }
        }
    }()

    return groups, errc
}
```

And here is the code that reads the channel to do the computations.

```
// Computes the results for the groups of data
func compute(done <-chan struct{}, groups <-chan model, c chan<- result) {
    for group := range groups {
        value := compute(group)

        select {
        case c <- result{value}:
        case <-done:
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: also a good way to find this sort of things is to try run it with -race

Comment: -race didn't produce anything different. The goroutines are created, all the work is completed, and then it doesn't exit since some of the goroutines are still alive.

Comment: can you post a gist of a runnable code ?

Comment: I created an example at http://play.golang.org/p/T7zBCYLECp. Looks like there is deadlock but I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: Why do you write `groups <- group` as `select { case groups <- group: }` ?

Comment: There were originally other channels, when I simplified it for the question I just deleted the ones not relevant and didn't change the clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're trying to read from `errc` and it's empty unless there's an error.

//edit

`computeAll()` will always block on `<- errc` if there are no errors, another approach is to use something like:

```
func computeAll() (err error) {
    .........
    select {
    case err = <-errc:
    default: //don't block
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: I updated the code, I actually use a separate if statement to try and read errc. This doesn't change the fact that the workers are not being cancelled. Or did you mean something different?

Comment: `if err := <-errc; err != nil` is blocking unless something closes or sends an error to `errc`

Comment: That didn't change anything, the code still never exits.

Comment: That was it.  So the code at http://blog.golang.org/pipelines/bounded.go has the same problem right? If there is no error than it will block forever?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60040/discussion-between-oneofone-and-bill).

Comment: I think @OneOfOne 's answer is right .I'm a little confused about your problem `This doesn't change the fact that the workers are not being cancelled. `, your works actully exit . here http://play.golang.org/p/D9nNrz421d

Comment: And  blog.golang.org/pipelines/bounded.go doesn't have the problem as yours. Its errc has be put something in . In the `func walkFiles` , `errc <- filepath.Walk(root, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error { ...})`

Answer (score 1):

Try to close the errc as OneOfOne says

```
go func() {
    wg.Wait()
    close(c)
    close(errc)
}()

// log the results of the computation
for r := range c { // log the results }

if err := range errc {
   if err != nil {
    return err
   }
}
```

Comment: Can't close(errc) since it is a receive only channel. Changing the `errc` handling (I assume you meant `for err := range errc`) didn't change anything.